# error_handlers page not show when deployed

Tags: php, google-app-engine, error-handling, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I am new to google app engine, and want to host my php website on it. I found that there is a error_handlers option to redirect error(missing page) to custom error page, but when deployed, the error page never show.

I have try it with local server using dev_appserver.py app.yaml and it works. If I enter a file that is not exist, it will redirect to the error page. But when deployed to the web, it doesn't work.

This is my app.yaml. If the URL is not a php or html file, just simply redirect to index.php. But if it is a php or html file but not found, it will go to error.html.

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
# Serve images as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$
  application_readable: true

# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.(php\html))$
  script: \1

- url: /.*
  script: index.php

error_handlers:
  - file: error.html
```

In local server, it works fine and show the error page. When deployed, 404 error will appear for missing php or html. The error.html will never show, even if the URL is (domain).com/error.html. 404 error will show for error.html

I wonder if it is possible to redirect missing page to custom error page.

Answer (score 0):

In your **app.yaml** I think you are missing a `\` in `- url: /(.+\.(php\html))$` like this: `/(.+\.(php\\html))$`

`error_handlers` only works for timeouts, over quota, and dos api denial errors.

It seems to me that you are redirecting all your urls to index.php and creating the appropriated handler there for each url. In that case, you should catch the errors there with [set_error_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

For the 404, I will recommend the following:

```
handlers:
 -url:/
  script: index.php

 -url:/*.
  script: 404_custom_error.php
```

In this case, any url that can not be handled inside the index.php will then be handled by the 404 custom error php script, as shown in the [app.yaml example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#example).

I found two public issue trackers discussing this topic. The first has info on a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35894282) and the second explains that the [infrastructure will not intercept](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35891137) valid 404 responses.